# Discrepancy in curve fit using solutions from solve_ivp and odeint

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Here's a basic example equation that I am trying to fit to an example data.

[image: \frac{dx}{dt} = -k x]

The goal is to find the best fit of `k` for my data assuming the data follows the above equation. An obvious way to do so is to numerically integrate the equation and then use curve fitting methods to minimise the least squares and get `k`.

Numerically integrating using [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) and [`ivp_solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) and using them on [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) produced rather drastic differences. The older `odeint` produced a better fit compared to newer `solve_ivp`. Best fit values of `k` are very different too.

```
Best fit k using ivp = [2.74421966]
Best fit k using odeint = [161.82220545]
```

What could be the reason behind this?

[image: Discrepancy]

```
## SciPy, NumPy etc imports here

N_SAMPLES = 20
rnd = np.random.default_rng(12345)
times = np.sort(rnd.choice(rnd.uniform(0, 1, 100), N_SAMPLES))
vals = np.logspace(10, 0.1, N_SAMPLES) + rnd.uniform(0, 1, N_SAMPLES)


def using_ivp(t, k):
    eqn = lambda t, x, k: -k * x
    y0 = vals[0]
    sol = solve_ivp(eqn, t, y0=[y0], args=(k, ),
                    dense_output=True)
    return sol.sol(t)[0]

def using_odeint(t, k):
    eqn = lambda x, t: -k * x
    y0 = vals[0]
    sol = odeint(eqn, y0, t)
    return sol[:,0]
    
tfit = np.linspace(min(times), max(times), 100)


#Fitting using ivp
k_fit1, kcov1 = curve_fit(using_ivp, times, vals, p0=1.3)
fit1 = using_ivp(tfit, k_fit1)


#Fitting using odeint
k_fit2, kcov2 = curve_fit(using_odeint, times, vals, p0=1.3)
fit2 = using_odeint(tfit, k_fit2)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.plot(times, vals, 'ro', label='data')
plt.plot(tfit, fit1, 'r-', label='using ivp')
plt.plot(tfit, fit2, 'b-', label='using odeint')
plt.legend(loc='best');

print('Best fit k using ivp = {}\n'\
      'Best fit k using odeint = {}\n'.\
      format(k_fit1, k_fit2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check again what the input arguments of `solve_ivp` are. The integration interval is given by the first two numbers in the `t_span` argument, so in your application most values in `sol.sol(t)` are obtained via wild extrapolation.

Correct that by giving the interval as `[min(t),max(t)]`.

To get more compatible computations, explicitly set the error tolerances, as the default values need not be equal. For instance `atol=1e-22, rtol=1e-9` so that only the relative tolerance has an effect.

It is curious how you use the `args` mechanism. It was only recently introduced to `solve_ivp` to be more compatible with `odeint`. I would not use it in either case here, as the definition of the parameter and its use is contained in a 3-line block. It has its uses where proper encapsulation and isolation from other code is a real concern.

Comment: I used the interval in this line inside `using_ivp` function: `sol = solve_ivp(eqn, [min(times), max(times)], y0=[y0], args=(k, ),  dense_output=True)`. And I got very close results to `odeint`. Indeed `solve_ivp` does some wild extrapolation if the range of integration is not given!

Comment: It does not really matter here, as they are the same by construction, but for code consistency it would be better to use the locally defined `t` array instead of the global `times` array. This is also an encapsulation/isolation concern.

Comment: indeed, it is right to use min, max of `t` rather than the global `times` in this case.